# WebGL: Determining maximum number of gl.POINTS per draw call

Tags: webgl

I am working on a scene in which I want to squeeze as many `gl.POINTS` as possible into each draw call. I thought I had remembered hearing that most devices only allow one to draw 2**16 vertices per draw call, but I've been able to draw ~250,000 points per draw call on my local machine!

Having examined [MDN's list of gl parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/getParameter) and queried for many of these values, I'm still uncertain: how can one determine the maximum number of `gl.POINTS` that can be included in a single draw call? Is this value somehow distinct from the maximum number of vertices that can be included per draw call when using other geometric primitives (e.g. triangle strip)? Any insight others can offer on this question would be very appreciated!

Comment: Not sure where you got that number, but I just ran a test with 1 million points (looked like a bloody snowstorm), and `WebGLRenderer.info.render.calls` reported a great big `1`. I'm also not sure whether there are other implications there (maybe that number isn't accurate, but it's the only place I know to get that data).

Comment: It would be better to ask either WebGL **OR** three.js questions. If I tell you WebGL can only do X that doesn't mean three.js hasn't programmed some way around that limit. three.js != WebGL

Comment: @gman yes I hear that. I just thought those who are tuned into the Three.js channel may know about this question, so I added the tag. I'll only use the Three.js tag for questions that involve the Three.js api in the future...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit is only in indices (`gl.drawElements`). By default indices can only be 16 bit values (0 to 65535). There is no limit on plain buffers (`gl.drawArrays`). Well, "no limit" still means there's a limit on memory, 32 bit values, and time.

For `gl.drawElements` you can switch to using 32bit indicies by checking for and enabling the extension [`OES_element_index_uint`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/OES_element_index_uint/).

Comment: thanks very much for this helpful answer. If you might have a second, could I please ask you whether it ever makes sense to use `gl.drawArrays` rather than `gl.drawElements` -- I mean, can the increased i/o increase performance if one makes fewer draw calls due to the lack of a buffer size when using `gl.drawArrays`? Do you also mean the largest number of values to be sent to `gl.drawArrays` is 2**32-1? If you could provide a link to where I could read about memory and time limits I'd also be grateful. Sorry for all the questions--you are the guru!

Comment: One more question -- are you aware of any demos that really try to use all 2**32 indices? That seems outrageous.

Comment: I don't think they could use all 2^32 indices. Maybe on. higher end GPU but 2^32 indices requires 16gig of memory for the data to index plus memory for the indices . As for the time restriction, the browser and/or the OS will reset the GPU if a single draw command takes too long to run where too long is greater than a few seconds , maybe even just 1. I think asking the GPU to process 4 billion vertices is probably an example of that